# pivot table formatting lost on different rows

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

below is a screenshot from my pivot table.  I have a filter button that filters based on dates between to values.. this all works dandy.  The issue I have is that the INSTALL DATE column seems to be showing the Dates as a Date AND numerical format.. I dont understand how this is happening as the source column of the pivot table is date format.    Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the Format of the record with value "10/02/2019" is to be Checked. this is string. convert it to "Date" and try again!

Comment: This is the correct format.. I require the numbers to be show as dates.. this is the problem, it shows some as dates and others as numbers

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. the issue was that I had to change the source data column to text.